# Nested IF statements with exact OR values

Tags: excel, function, if-statement, nested

I'm new to Excel IF statements and am having trouble with what I believe is called a *nested IF function*. I've looked at other IF questions on here and they're too complicated for my novice brain to understand.

I have a column that has numbers in it. There are about a dozen different numbers. The numbers represent a specific team. For example, 100 is team red, 101 is team yellow, 102 is team green, etc. I need to create an IF statement that will tell me what each of the teams are based on the numbers. I have hundreds of rows to filter through and I don't want to do them manually if the function exists to automate it in Excel.

I tried to write my own nested IF statement and it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

```
=IF(B2="100",red,IF(B2="101",blue,IF(B2="103",green,IF(B2="104",yellow,""))))
```

Help?

Comment: ANSWERED: RocketDonkey's solution to use vlookup worked. Shout out to Dave Sexton for telling me how to properly identify numbers versus text when using IF statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nested `IF` statements are definitely mind-bending, and at least in my experience I still get confused :) You also run into an issue with certain versions of Excel where the number of nested `IF`'s you are allowed is limited. In conjunction with that, they become difficult to debug the more levels of nesting that are added. Regarding your current formula, @DaveSexton's suggestion of changing the strings to numbers (removing the quotes) should help. Also, make sure that you **are** quoting your color values in the formula, because using `red` (and not `"red"`) will cause a `#NAME?` error (assuming you haven't defined `red` already).

In your situation, have you thought about trying a `VLOOKUP` formula? Instead of hard-coding the team names in the formula itself, you would set up a table that would have a team number and the corresponding team name:

[image]

The formula here (in column `B2`) is:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,$D$2:$E$6,2,FALSE)
```

What this does is looks at cell `A2` and then goes to the table in range `D2:E6`, looking for the value of `A2` in column `D`. When it find it, it returns the value in column `E`, which would be the team name.

Comment: `VLOOKUP` is the easiest way. In addition, no more than 7 `IF` statements can be nested, IIRC

Comment: The limit is 7 nested functions in Excel 2003 or earlier - but in Excel 2007 that increased to 64

Comment: OH MY GOODNESS THIS VLOOKUP THING IS THE GREATEST THING *EVER*! You win all the awards. This totally worked. Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Comment: @office-rat Ha, no problem - enjoy! It may come up once or twice more in the future :)

Comment: @RocketDonkey I'm already going through other spreadsheets and changing my hack work to use vlookup instead :)

Comment: @office-rat Good to hear - once you get comfortable with `VLOOKUP`, the next step is `INDEX`/`MATCH`, which among other things will find a match at any position in a range (not just the first column) and return whatever you want. However focus on `VLOOKUP` first and understand that - it will make understanding more complex concepts much, much easier :)

Answer (score 3):

Your cells contain numbers but you are treating the numbers as text in your formula.

Better alternatives to nested IFs are VLOOKUP or CHOOSE like so:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,{100,"Red";101,"Blue";102,"Orange"},2)

=CHOOSE(A1-99,"Red","Blue","Orange")
```

Comment: So it should be more like: =IF(B2=100,"red",IF... etc.?

Comment: Exactly - I have also add some alternatives to nested IFs

Answer (score 0):

Hi I don't have access to excel to test this as I am not using windows but try the following it should work:

```
=IF(B1=100,0,IF(B1=101,1,IF(B1=102,2,IF(B1=103,3,IF(B1=104,4)))))
```

from the above you can say 
0 represents Red
1 represents blue and so on

Comment: Thanks! Between your reply and the one by Dave Sexton I was able to figure it out :)

Comment: No worry glad you sorted it :)