# Excel Nested IF's - varying number of nests

Tags: excel, nested-if

Background is that I have an excel sheet, which generates some expressions

[Example Pricing Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTsv6.png)

As an example, the expression that I need to create looks as follows (An arbitrary value of 0 is applied at the end, if none of the if's evaluate to true:

```
3000Span = if(Projection = '2500', 2726, if(Projection = '2750', 2844, if(Projection = '3000', 3030,if(Projection = '3250', 3183,0)
```

I've referenced the cells, so the formula is currently..

```
= B2 &"Span = if(Projection = '"& $A$3 &"', " & B3 & ", if(Projection = '"& $A$4 &"', " & B4 & ", if(Projection = '"& $A$5 &"', " & B5 & ",0)))"
```

Is there a more generalised way I can do this way that can cope with a variable number of rows, so if the supplier provides a new matrix that has more or fewer rows, the expression will just 'work', by creating the necessary number of nested ifs, terminating once a blank cell is reached in column A?

I don't mind how messy/complex the spreadsheet becomes, the end goal is to make the process of updating pricing expressions as simple as possible, by copy/pasting updated grids into A2 of the worksheet

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested IF statements with exact OR values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14198442/nested-if-statements-with-exact-or-values)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understand what you intend with the references but I think you are looking for a formula similar to this:

```
=ISERROR(VLOOKUP(lookupCell,A3:B5,2,FALSE),0)
```

Comment: For column headers, the measurement is SPAN, for row headers, the measurement is PROJECTION

My expression will be constructed of a name, which is Cell B2, followed by the word 'span', followed by '=' followed by the nested if

My nested if needs to be:

SPAN3000 = If A3 then B3, if A4 then B4, if A5 then B5, otherwise 0

If a value is entered into A6 and B6, then the formula needs to recognise this and output:

SPAN3000 = If A3 then B3, if A4 then B4, if A5 then B5, IF A6 then B6, otherwise 0

Comment: Similarly, if the grid is shortened and only contains values in row 3 and 4, then the formula needs to recognise this and output:

SPAN3000 = If A3 then B3, if A4 then B4, otherwise 0